# php merge multidimensional arrays into each other

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two multidimensional arrays in `php` and want to merge them.

**First one :**

```
array1 = (
    0 => array (
        0 => array(
            id => 1,
            name => "test"
        )
    )
    1 => array(...)
)
```

**Second one :**

```
array2 = (
    0 => array (
        0 => array(
            id => 200,
            name => "test"
        ),
        1 => array(
            id => 201,
            name => "test"
        )
    )
    1 => array(...)
)
```

And the **merged array** must be like this :

```
lastArray = (
    0 => array (
        0 => array(
            id =>1,
            name => "test"
        ),
        1 => array(
            id => 200,
            name => "test"
        ),
        2 => array (
            id => 201,
            name => "test"
        )
    )
    1 => array(...)
)
```

How should I do this with a proper `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Why not use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or [array-merge-recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) for this? This will **merge** the both (or more) arrays.

```
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$array = array_merge-recursive($array1, $array2);
```

**Method 2:**

Loop through one array.
(You may check if the key is equal to the others array key).

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$value) $array_2[$key] = $value;
```

*Reminder from splash58:* Don't forget to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in **both methods** to sort the array by values after sort by id

Comment: No! this is not this much simple. pay more attention for `lastArray` that I mentioned. I don't want to push it to the end of the first array!

Comment: After sort by id  with usort function  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1):

According to the `lastArray` that you've presented - you need to merge the inner arrays only at `0` position/index(and you didn't show how should look a merge result at `1` index).
Use the following approach:

```
$array1[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2[0]);
// now, $array1 is your $lastArray
```